# Java / Groovy generic type inference

Tags: java, generics, groovy, type-inference

I'm writing Groovy (1.8.8) code running under JDK6 and it seems the following is legal:

```
ConcurrentMap<Foo, Bar> statsRegistry = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()
```

Why is it permitted to omit the types on the right-hand side? Is this a NEW Groovy feature or would this also be allowed in Java 6?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: @baraky type inference was introduced in java 7, not java 6. question is about java 6 and groovy 1.8.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "diamond operator" (type inference) was introduced in Groovy 1.8, see [this item of the Release notes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy18releasenotes-Diamondoperator), and Groovy 1.8 works fine with JDK6.

Comment: Thanks for the release notes link